# How to set my App as default Home?

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I'm developing a Android desktop app, and I would like that when it first starts it (confirm with user and) set itself as default action for Home button.

Currently, this option is given to the user by the Android system only when he first press the Home button after running my app.

Actually, I want the "back" button to not return to the default desktop, as my app will be the default desktop. Maybe the solution for this is the same of the one for the Home button?

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this.

Comment: but I can see in some application, with that functionality. like GO Launcher app.

Comment: GO launcher is installed then automatically it appear as launcher, no need to click on home and select GO launcher in very first time. how can we get this functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just let the system do it for you when the user presses the Home button for the first time. It's what the user is expecting. He/she doesn't expect it to change automatically and personally I would find that quite annoying if it did that since I like choosing my Home screen constantly.

As for the back button, simply add an `onKeyDown/Up` handler for the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` event to return `true` (meaning handled by you, not the system). If you do that, it will not leave your app.